# PHP Array Iterator to DIV

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I want to loop through the unknown depth array with `RecursiveIteratorIterator` in `SELF::FIRST` mode along with `RecursiveArrayIterator`.

If the array value is an array, I will open a DIV so the "subarray" will be inside this DIV. Something like

```
$array = array(
    'key0' => '0',
    'key1' => array(
        'value0' => '1',
        'value1' => '2',
    ),
    'key2' => '3',
    'key3' => array(
        'value2' => '4',
        'value3' => array(
            'value4' => '5'
        ),
        'value4' => array(
            'value5' => '6'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then the HTML should be:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>key0 is 0</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>key1</p>
        <div>
            <p>value0 is 1</p>
            <p>value1 is 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>key2 is 3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>key3</p>
        <div>
            <p>value2 is 4</p>
            <p>value3</p>
            <div>
                <p>value4 is 5</p>
            </div>
            <p>value4</p>
            <div>
                <p>value5 is 6</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is my code can only close 1 `<div>` tag each time. I have no idea how to remember how deep was there. So I can close to a for loop and `echo` `</div>`.

---

My current code:

```
<?php

    echo '<div>';

    $iterator      = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($iterator_array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $is_start      = true;
    $last_element  = '';

    foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value) && $is_start) {

            echo '<div><p>' . $key . '</p>';

            $is_start     = false;
            $last_element = end($value);
        } elseif(is_array($value) && !$is_start) {

            echo '</div><div><p>' . $key . '</p>';

            $last_element = end($value);
        } elseif(!is_array($value)) {

            echo '<div><p>' . $key . ' is ' . $value . '</p></div>';

            if($last_element == $value) {
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: maybe using smthng among lines of "array.lenght()" to check how many divs you need? Just trying to think outside the box. (lenght of array = 4, 4 INITIAL divs, inside array[key1].lenght = 2, then 2 divs more...)

Comment: Do you really need to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator`? It looks like a job for a simple recursive function.

Comment: with `$iterator->getDepth()` you can get the level on which you while an iteration. Test of its changes

Comment: @JakubMatczak Maybe not, but I tried and no luck.

Comment: @splash58 Thanks for the advice. I have got all Depth but this doesn't help much. As sometimes the array's depth will decrease more than 1 and I don't know what to do next ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this recursive function

May be it will help you

```
    get_div($array);
    function get_div($arr) {
        foreach($arr as $k => $a){
            echo '<div>';
            if(is_array($a)) {
                echo "<p>".$k."</p>";
                get_div($a);
            } else {
                echo "<p>".$k." is ".$a."</p>";
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```